# how to make List<List> different length inside list

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to make list inside a list so if:

```
List<String> dataList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' , '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18' , '19', '20', '21', '22'];
List<int> dataListLength = [5 , 7, 10];
List<List<String>> listList = [];
```

I want it like this:

`listList[0]` -> `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`,

`listList[1]` -> `['6', '7', '8', '9', '10' , '11', '12']`

`listList[2]` -> `['13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18' , '19', '20', '21', '22']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
List<String> dataList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' , '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18' , '19', '20', '21', '22'];
List<int> dataListLength = [5 , 7, 10];
List<List<String>> listList = [];
  int start = 0;
  for(var i in dataListLength){
    List<String> temp = [];
    for(int j=start; j<i+start; j++){
      temp.add(dataList[j]);
    }
    listList.add(temp);
    start += i;
  }
  print(listList);
```

result

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code.

**i think you can use this function `List.getRange(int, int)`**

In Dart, you don't need to specify the list size.

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> dataList = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' , '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18' , '19', '20', '21', '22'];
  
  List<List> listList = [dataList.getRange(0,4).toList(), 
                     dataList.getRange(5,11).toList(),
                     dataList.getRange(11,21).toList()];
  
  print(listList);
  
}
```